# Start an animation with delay or scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I currently have a website with animation that start after 5s (with the use of the JQuery delay function). My problem is that I'm trying to add also the possibility to start these animations on scroll so it let the user the possibility to skip the animation when he scrolls. I already tried to put an if statement but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $(".container-title").delay(5000).animate({top : "10rem"}, 1500);
    } else if ($(window).width() < 1192 && $(window).width() >= 767) {
        $(".container-title").delay(5000).animate({width : "730px", top : "9rem"}, 1500);
    } else if ($(window).width() > 1192) {
        $(".container-title").delay(5000).animate({top : "9rem", width : "677px"}, 1500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code needs to be refactored for better understanding and maintaining.

Comment: It is quite unclear to understand the requirement based on code added?

Comment: I just edited the code to make it more understandable. To summarize, I want to start the animation after a delay of 5s after the page is loaded (already working) BUT if I scroll I want to skip the delay and directly start the animation without the delay (trying to make it work)